# What all factors affect the ability of a video player to play a particular file?

Tags: video, codec, media-player, matroska

I am trying to determine what all factors decide whether a file can be played by a particular video player, such as software or dvd player or TV with usb function or any media player.

Are there other factors other than video codec that can prevent the player from supporting a particular video ? If so can someone list them ?

I have an idea where I will create a program to create a bunch of videos, using various combinations / permutations of codecs / frame rates etc . Then it would make it really easy to see where exactly any player fails.

Thanks

Comment: Codec support is the main item to consider. The other considerations are primarilly performance based. What exactly are you after? have you ever looked into g-spot? http://www.headbands.com/gspot/

Comment: I have , but afaik g-spot will only help with PC based media players for particular files.

Comment: well, while it does evaluate the codecs installed on the system, more primarilly it helps tell you which codecs a peice of video uses. Then you just determine whether Player/Device X implements those codecs. That would seem to accomplish what you are looking for. As I said, I'm unclear what your endgame is. why are you interested in determining the playability of a file against every device/player there is?

Comment: Endgame: create files with various combinations/permutations of codecs (and other factors) via a script, then put them on a usb drive, and play them on my video player one by one, this way I will know exactly where my video player fails. I don't want to check against EVERY player, it just that the above method CAN be used against any player. Hope I was clear.

Answer (score 0):

There can be hardware issues, video and audio renderers failing due to the hardware or driver's inability to support a particular colorspace or audio format.

Some players allow you to switch renderers to get around these issues, Zoom Player for example.